# Vaccination for Nepal

Tags: health, nepal, kathmandu

I'm intending to go to Nepal (specifically Kathmandu and Pokhara) for 19 days trip, starting on 4th of April.

After some research I've found that it's common to take vaccinations for Hepatitus A and Typhoid, while for long stays it's also recommended to get Hepatitus B, Japanese Encephalitis and take anti-malarial drugs.

I'll mainly visit tourist places and do a five-day hike in Pokhara,and I don't intend to go to Chitwan nor visit the jungles.

My question which of these vaccinations are really important to take Hepatitus A & Typhoid  vaccinations?

Comment: Typhoid and Hep B is compulsory. Water borne diseases are more prone in South Asia. But it is little weird that you are from Egypt and still need to ask.

Comment: @DumbCoder, if you mean that those diseases are common in Egypt as like as Nepal and i'm ok so far in Egypt , that would mean that vaccination is not important ,ain't it?. i don't see any point for you saying so !

Comment: First of all no need to get so wishy washy. The points you raised are more so important for people from developed countries, who aren't immune from some tropical diseases, which are common in the tropics. And being from Egypt you might be immune to some(not Hepatitis B and typhoid), but worthwhile to take precautions.

Comment: To complete the list, there's also the question if one should do a rabies vaccination or not.

Answer (score 6):

How do we determine whether or not it's important?  Obviously if you know you're going to get sick, getting it is essential, but with something that's not guaranteed, just highly likely, you can't put a figure on 'really important' or not.

However, we can listen to experts and see what they say.

- [CDC (Center for Disease Control)](http://wwwnc.cdc.gov/travel/destinations/traveler/none/Nepal) - Hep A is recommended for most travellers, irrespective of where you are going, and Typhoid is recommended for most travellers, *especially* if staying with friends or you are an adventurous eater.
- [Lonely Planet](http://www.lonelyplanet.com/nepal/practical-information/health) - both recommended for your consideration.
- [Ciwec Clinic](http://ciwec-clinic.com/health-information/immunizations-recommended-for-travel-in-nepal/) - both recommended
- [IAMAT - International Association for Medical Assistance to Travellers](http://www.iamat.org/country_profile.cfm?id=72#profile_immunization)- both come under their 'recommended' category.

Nobody likes getting injections, but given all these international groups for travellers and disease control ALL recommend getting them, it'd be considered foolish by many to risk it, even if you're there for just a few days.

However, if it's the injections that are really worrying you, what you could consider is that [Lonely Planet](http://www.lonelyplanet.com/nepal/practical-information/health) mentions there is now a combined hepatitis A-typhoid vaccine, AND that you can take typhoid medicine as oral caplets, instead of the injection.

Answer (score 5):

Officially Nepal don't ask travelers any immunization to come inside country. But it may differ if you are travelling from the country where yellow fever is present.

[Reference from Lonelyplanet](http://www.lonelyplanet.com/nepal/health)